# using functions inside constructors php

Tags: php, oop

In an effort to keep my code clean, I am attempting to replace a whole bunch of code in my constructor with a function.  I believe I am calling the function correctly but i'm not able to assign values to the variables as intended.

```
public function __construct($docID) {

    self::getDocumentInfo($docID);
    self::getTranscriptionInfo($docID);

}

private static function getTranscriptionInfo($docID) {
    $this->documentTranscription = 5;
}
```

Im getting an error "PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in ...".  This is simplified for postings purpose, but would it be better just have a very large constructor and skip the functions all together?  Or is their a better way to assign values?

Comment: you should change your `$this` to `self::`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static method is not a part of the class instance.  The static keyword means the method can be called within your class but it won't have any of the instance variables.

Remove the `static` keyword and change this:

```
self::getDocumentInfo($docID);
self::getTranscriptionInfo($docID);
```

to this:

```
$this->getDocumentInfo($docID);
$this->getTranscriptionInfo($docID);
```

Using `$this` means it will be calling it within the right instance context.

Some info the static keyword (added emphasis in italics):

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).
>
> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, *the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static*.
>
> **Source**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Ok, that is very understandable.  Thank you!